# Ошибки при проверке на тип данных в методе c#

Tags: c#, объекты, task

У меня есть метод, который считывает данные с файла в двумерный массив object, исходных данные:

```
1950;событие 1 бла-бла-бла   
1991-06-01;какое-то событие 3  
2000-01-01;наступил миллениум, ура-ура-ура
```

Мне нужно, чтобы они считались и записались в него, проблема заключается в том, что первая строчка имеет первое значение типа int, а все остальные DateTime, я вроде бы написал проверку на тип данных, но она не работает, сам весь код корректный если убрать только первую строчку, в ней вся проблема.
Ошибка которую выдает компилятор: "System.FormatException: String '1950' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
*Сам метод:*

```
static object[][] ReadDataObjectForTimeline(string filePath)
        {
            var readedFile = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            object[][] splitData = new object[readedFile.Length][];

            for (var i = 0; i < readedFile.Length; i++)
            {
                var line = readedFile[i];
                string[] parts = line.Split(";");

                object[] values = new object[parts.Length];
                if (values[0] is int)
                    values[0] = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                else
                    values[0] = DateTime.Parse(parts[0]);
                values[1] = parts[1];

                splitData[i] = values;
            }
            return splitData;
        }
```

Comment: Дело в том, что values[0] еще не int, его только можно преобразовать к int. Используйте TryParse

Comment: @demonplus Выполнять проверку TryParse прям в условии или до этого?

Comment: if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out myInt)) {values [0] = myInt;}

Comment: Да просто временная переменная типа int конечно же :)

Comment: Придумайте ей хорошее имя сами

Comment: Немного не понимаю, сейчас попробую почитать про out

Comment: {values [0] = myInt;} А что это такое у вас в скобках? out как я понял просто возвращает нам значение, которое мне как раз и нужно

Comment: А число может встречаться только в первой строке, или еще и в других строках может встречаться?

Comment: В теории и в других может

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`values[0] is int` вернет всегда `false`, потому что `values[0]` у вас `null`, вы туда еще ничего не записали. Быть может вы хотели `parts[0] is int` написать, но и это бы тоже не сработало, потому что `parts[0]` - это `string`.

Этот процесс называется десереализация.

Самый простой способ разобрать, это создать класс для данных, а не мучаться с вложенными массивами.

```cs
public class Item
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

И далее десереализовать в массив таких объектов

```cs
public Item[] ParseFile(string path)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    Item[] result = new Item[lines.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] tokens = lines[i].Split(';');
        result[i] = new Item
        {
            Date = DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], out DateTime date) ? date : DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[0], "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Text = tokens[1]
        };
    }
    return result;
}
```

То есть то число как я понял, не `int`, а год от даты, поэтому его тоже можно сохранить в `DateTime`.

А чтобы не мучаться с ручным разбором CSV, есть готовый NuGet пакет **CSVHelper**.

---

Вариант с вложенным массивом и интом.

```cs
public object[][] ParseFile(string path)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    object[][] result = new object[lines.Length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] tokens = lines[i].Split(';');
        result[i] = new object[]
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], out DateTime date) ? date : int.Parse(tokens[0]),
            tokens[1]
        };
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня задача стоит в том, чтобы работать с object[][]

Comment: Так все верно, у меня примерно похожий метод есть в коде для работы с двумерным массивом, но суть задачи поставленной передо мной в том, чтобы считать все в двумерный массив, а мне вот не удается

Comment: @IlyaKvashin зря ответ, получается писал? Ну как попытаться спарсить дату а при неуспехе попробовать другой способ, я вам показал. Тип выходных данных на самом деле не имеет значения. И это не двухмерный массив у вас,а вложенный. Массив массивов.

Comment: @IlyaKvashin дополнил ответ.

Comment: @aepot `потому что values[0] у вас string` - не так. values[0] - это object

Comment: @AndreiKhotko исправил, спасибо.

Comment: @aepot Это замена буквально моему методу?

Comment: ` {
            DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], out DateTime date) ? date : int.Parse(tokens[0]),
            tokens[1]
        };` Эти строки немного сложны для понимания, попробовал просто заменить мой метод вашим сработало когда добавил static

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin [Тернарный оператор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться!